# Disposing TcpClient when having a reference to NetworkStream

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, tcpclient, networkstream

Say I have the following code:

```
public static Client Connect(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    if (!useSsl)
    {
        return new Client(tcpClient.GetStream());
    }
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
    return new Client(sslStream);
}
```

When I compile this, Code Analysis says me that I should dispose `tcpClient` before the reference is out of scope. The problem is that I need to use the underlying stream instance further and I can't dispose the `tcpClient` here. Simultaneously, I don't want to store a reference to the `tcpClient` somewhere in order to dispose later as I need the stream only. What is the right solution here? Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem with storing a reference to the `tcpClient` ?

Comment: now are you wanting to return a SSLStream or Client if so change the return in my example and the Method Signature..

Comment: @Yahia There supposed to be many of `Client` instances. However, the `Client` class needs a `Stream` instance as the parameter only and I want to leave it independent from the `TcpClient` class.

Comment: question when you return the new Client(sslStream) is it null or do you have the expected stream.. if it has the expected stream then just null out the tcpClient before the return call.. please clarify..

Comment: Perhaps changing the Connect method from a static method to an instance method (or even the constructor), then and make your TcpClient object part of the Client class.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I've corrected the question. As I said below, the problem is a need to use the underlying stream while the `tcpClient` should be disposed.

Comment: Look at Matthew's remarks as well.. I was thinking that as well but sometimes the individuals whom ask questions are reluctant to change method signatures but he's got a valid point.. +1

Comment: @Matthew I understand this workaround, but is this good to refer the `TcpClient` class while the `Client` needs a `Stream` only?

Comment: if you only need the Stream then do not return new Client(sslStream) just return the Stream and change your method to allow for a Stream public static SSLStream Connect(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl)

Comment: AFAIK if you dispose of the TcpClient, it will invalidate the stream.  If you use just the stream and don't save the TcpClient object, then it will just be picked up by the GAC and you don't get to control disposal yourself.  The object will be in memory anyway.

Comment: @Matthew So the conclusion is just leave my code as is?

Comment: It will probably work the majority of the time, however since you said you are creating a lot of connections, it would be best to explicitly close connections when they are no longer working.

Comment: @Matthew Ok. Please, post this as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient = null;

    public Client(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl) // c'tor
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);

        if (!useSsl)
        {
            Init(tcpClient.GetStream());
            return;
        }

        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);

        Init(sslStream);            
    }

    private void Init(Stream stream)
    {
        // bla bla bla
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {  
        // this implementation of Dispose is potentially faulty (it is for illustrative purposes only)
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

        if( tcpClient != null ) {
            tcpClient.Close();
            tcpClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this in two ways..
1. pass the var by ref or
2. declare a private variable at the top as 
   SslStream sslStream = null;
have this

```
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
```

change it or the method to read as the following.

```
public static SSLStream Connect(ref string hostname, ref int port, bool useSsl) 
{     
   TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
   if (!useSsl) 
   {
      return new Client(tcpClient.GetStream());
   }
   sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream()); // or the ref sslStream 
   sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
   tcpClient = null; or if implements IDisposable then do this
   if (tcpClient != null)
   {
      ((IDisposable)tcpClient).Dispose();
   }
   return sslStream; //if yo
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with `SslStream` specifically. The problem is that  `tcpClient` should be disposed while the underlying stream - no.

Comment: yeah but when you dispose of the tcpClient you are returning a SSLStream now the GAC could kick in perhaps once that sslStream variable is out of scope but by the looks of things I am assuming that you are using that sslStream after the return call .. does this make sense..?